# C++ Regex for 0=250|18000=300|26000=0.86M

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to write a regex in C++ that would match any of the following statements:

```
0=250
26000=0.86M
0=250|18000=300
0=250|18000=300|26000=0.86M
```

I wrote the following and checked with regexr.com:

```
(([0-9]+=[0-9]+)|((\|[0-9]+=[0-9]|.[0-9]+)[Mm]))((\|[0-9]+=[0-9]+)|((\|[0-9]+=[0-9]|.[0-9]+)[Mm])?)+
```

It looks like it is working, but I do not understand one thing. I thought I needed double backslashes before ".", like:

```
(([0-9]+=[0-9]+)|((\|[0-9]+=[0-9]\\.[0-9]+)[Mm]))((\|[0-9]+=[0-9]+)|((\|[0-9]+=[0-9]\\.[0-9]+)[Mm])?)+
```

as I was advised in my other post. However, according to the online tester, this is not correct.

Can someone explain please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you will need to escape many things when you use it in actual c++ code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the flavor of regex that you are using. Regex doesn't have universal rules, and some of the main differences are what characters need to be escaped when.

I don't know what flavor your online tester was, but here is what c++ 11 uses for regex: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/

You will need to escape all literal `.` and `|` characters in your regex according to this.

Comment: Thank you! I could not find a good original c++ regex online tester, but the code with escapes seems to work in the actual program.